# Working thru simple Java "Choose your own adventure" text game

Tags: java

I am new to Java and coding in general. I have started working thru [these tutorials](http://programmingbydoing.com/) with great success, until I got to [this one](http://programmingbydoing.com/a/choose-your-own-short-adventure.html). I know in my code I have not entered the option of going "upstairs" yet, because I wanted to make sure the "kitchen" option worked correctly first.

The code compiles fine, however when I run it in a cmd line, I am able to choose the first option of going into the "kitchen" but when I choose to view the "pantry" it takes 2 cmd lines with "pantry" to execute actually looking into it.

Also, if I choose the option to "run away" after looking in the "pantry", it does not println the text with the "run away" option.

Sorry if there are easier ways to do this, however I have not learned them yet.

Thanks for any help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Adventure1
{
public static void main( String[] args ){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

String Go, Look, Pantry, Eat;

System.out.println( " WELCOME TO MY TINY ADVENTURE");
System.out.println("  ");
System.out.println( " You are in a creepy house! Would you like to go 'upstairs' or into the 'kitchen'? ");
System.out.print( "> ");
Go = keyboard.next();

if (Go.equalsIgnoreCase("kitchen"))
{System.out.println("There is a long countertop with dirty dishes everywhere. Off to one side there is, as you'd expect, a refrigerator. You may open the 'refrigerator' or look in the 'pantry'. ");}
System.out.print(">  ");
Look = keyboard.next();


    if (Look.equalsIgnoreCase( "refrigerator" ))
{System.out.println("Inside the refrigerator you see food and stuff. It looks pretty nasty. Would you like to eat some of the food, 'Yes' or 'No'?");}
System.out.print(">  ");
Eat = keyboard.next();

        if (Eat.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
    {System.out.println("  ");
    System.out.println("You live!");}

        else if (Eat.equalsIgnoreCase("No"))
    {System.out.println("  ");
    System.out.println("You die of starvation!");}



else if (Look.equalsIgnoreCase( "pantry" ))
{System.out.println("There is a killer inside. Do you want to 'fight' them, or 'run away'?");}
System.out.print(">  ");
Pantry = keyboard.next();

        if (Pantry.equalsIgnoreCase("fight"))
    {System.out.println("  ");
    System.out.println("You're weak and die");}

        else if(Pantry.equalsIgnoreCase("run away"))
    {System.out.println("  ");
    System.out.println("You died because your too slow & can't run");}

}

    }
```

Comment: Consider using `nextLine` instead of just `next`, it's possible that there is still a new line character in the buffer

Comment: The run away option is failing because there are two words: taking .next() only returns "run", so the comparison to "run away" fails, and it doesn't enter that block. Using .nextLine() would solve this.

Comment: When asking the user if they want to look in the `refrigerator` or `pantry`, you check to see if the response is `refrigerator` and then prompt the user for more input (regardless), so if the user enters `pantry`, you skip over the `refrigerator` straight into the next "prompt"

Comment: I'm suprised it hadn't been mentioned before, but I have a small nit to pick. In Java, variables begin with lowercase letters and follow camelCase, i.e. `go`, `look`, etc. Things beginning with uppercase letters include things like class names, i.e. `Adventure1`, as you already have. It's good to get into this habit now, it makes code easier to read for everybody involved, and can help minimize confusion. You'll notice even SO's syntax highlighter is assuming the uppercase names are class names and highlighting them differently than other variables like `keyboard`.

Comment: @AndrewG thank you a lot for mentioning this. This is very helpful, because I had no idea. I'll implement this in the future!

Comment: @dzur19 Of course! Java has a language specification regarding all of these "rules"  which I would link to if I weren't on my phone at the moment.  I'm sure you could find it fairly easily, or maybe another kind soul will drop by with a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the logic for this section...

```
if (Go.equalsIgnoreCase("kitchen")) {
    System.out.println("There is a long countertop with dirty dishes everywhere. Off to one side there is, as you'd expect, a refrigerator. You may open the 'refrigerator' or look in the 'pantry'. ");
}
System.out.print(">  ");
Look = keyboard.next();

if (Look.equalsIgnoreCase("refrigerator")) {
    System.out.println("Inside the refrigerator you see food and stuff. It looks pretty nasty. Would you like to eat some of the food, 'Yes' or 'No'?");
}
System.out.print(">  ");
Eat = keyboard.next();
```

If the user enters the "kitchen", you prompt them for `refrigerator` or `pantry`, if they enter `pantry`, you go straight to a empty prompt, you've not actually handled the eventuality that the user might enter something else other then `refrigerator`

Your entire logic chain is broken, you're not separating the sections into individual blocks of logic to handle the current scenario.

For example, something like...

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

String Go, Look, Pantry, Eat;

System.out.println(" WELCOME TO MY TINY ADVENTURE");
System.out.println("  ");
System.out.println(" You are in a creepy house! Would you like to go 'upstairs' or into the 'kitchen'? ");
System.out.print("> ");
Go = keyboard.next();

if (Go.equalsIgnoreCase("kitchen")) {
    System.out.println("There is a long countertop with dirty dishes everywhere. Off to one side there is, as you'd expect, a refrigerator. You may open the 'refrigerator' or look in the 'pantry'. ");
    System.out.print(">  ");
    Look = keyboard.next();

    if (Look.equalsIgnoreCase("refrigerator")) {
        System.out.println("Inside the refrigerator you see food and stuff. It looks pretty nasty. Would you like to eat some of the food, 'Yes' or 'No'?");
        System.out.print(">  ");
        Eat = keyboard.next();

        if (Eat.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
            System.out.println("  ");
            System.out.println("You live!");
        } else if (Eat.equalsIgnoreCase("No")) {
            System.out.println("  ");
            System.out.println("You die of starvation!");
        }
    } else if (Look.equalsIgnoreCase("pantry")) {
        System.out.println("There is a killer inside. Do you want to 'fight' them, or 'run away'?");
        System.out.print(">  ");
        Pantry = keyboard.next();

        if (Pantry.equalsIgnoreCase("fight")) {
            System.out.println("  ");
            System.out.println("You're weak and die");
        } else if (Pantry.equalsIgnoreCase("run away")) {
            System.out.println("  ");
            System.out.println("You died because your too slow & can't run");
        }
    }
}
```

would group each logic block into it's own group.  This would then lead you to the ability to actually use methods to further isolate the logic.

The next problem you will have to over come is what do to when they don't enter what you're expecting

Another problem you will face is `Scanner#next` will return the next work, so something like `run away` won't work.  Instead you might consider using `Scanner#nextLine` instead

Answer (score 1):

Your logic was off. Look at where the pantry actually was.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Adventure1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    String Go, Look, Pantry, Eat;

    System.out.println(" WELCOME TO MY TINY ADVENTURE");
    System.out.println("  ");
    System.out
        .println(" You are in a creepy house! Would you like to go 'upstairs' or into the 'kitchen'? ");
    System.out.print("> ");
    Go = keyboard.next();

    if (Go.equalsIgnoreCase("kitchen")) {
        System.out
            .println("There is a long countertop with dirty dishes everywhere. Off to one side there is, as you'd expect, a refrigerator. You may open the 'refrigerator' or look in the 'pantry'. ");
    }
    System.out.print(">  ");
    Look = keyboard.next();

    if (Look.equalsIgnoreCase("refrigerator")) {
        System.out
            .println("Inside the refrigerator you see food and stuff. It looks pretty nasty. Would you like to eat some of the food, 'Yes' or 'No'?");
    } else if (Look.equalsIgnoreCase("pantry")) {
        System.out
            .println("There is a killer inside. Do you want to 'fight' them, or 'run away'?");
        Pantry = keyboard.next();

        if (Pantry.equalsIgnoreCase("fight")) {
        System.out.println("  ");
        System.out.println("You're weak and die");
        }

        else if (Pantry.equalsIgnoreCase("run away")) {
        System.out.println("  ");
        System.out
            .println("You died because your too slow & can't run");
        }
    }
    System.out.print(">  ");
    Eat = keyboard.next();

    if (Eat.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
        System.out.println("  ");
        System.out.println("You live!");
    }

    else if (Eat.equalsIgnoreCase("No")) {
        System.out.println("  ");
        System.out.println("You die of starvation!");
    }
    System.out.print(">  ");

    }

}
```